# Ignore dots or periods in URLs with nginx

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, nginx, vite

I'm using **Vite** in development mode using Docker at my local machine (Windows 10). Local custom domain won't load because the required script can't be loaded.

`/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=803526f2`

It returns **403 Forbidden** error.

In console, it says:

`/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=803526f2" module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("text/html")`

---

I found out that my nginx has this:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}
```

It causes to block the URL because it contains period e.g `/.vite/`.
I tried deleting the nginx code and it works. However, it's not good in terms of security.
Any better ideas? I'm looking for nginx rule code that will allow /.vite/ to pass so it will not be blocked.

Comment: It's unclear what happens in your case. Files in /node_modules/.vite/ are used in Vite devserver. You aren't supposed to run it in production environment.

Comment: I'm using docker in development mode at my local windows machine

Comment: Files inside node_modules are not the issue. What I'm trying to say is that nginx blocked that URL because it includes "dot" (/.vite/), that's why it returns 403. I'm looking for nginx rule code that will allow /.vite/ to pass so it will not be blocked.

Comment: Usually you don't need nginx to handle devserver traffic. If it's so for some reason then you don't have to worry about security concerns, exactly because you run it on local machine, this rule just shouldn't be there

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know the meaning of location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}  I'm guessing it's the root cause of the problem because after I deleted it, the application runs. But what if I'll deploy it online, is it still safe to delete that rule?

Comment: If you deploy it online, you'd keep the rule, however in that case you wouldn't use a dev server either, so there also wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @dizon.ben That's exactly what this rule is responsible for, to not allow dotted files to be served because they often contain sensitive info. You need just a different config for local to make it work ok. If you don't want to deal with multiple configs then the answer is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to ignore `.vite` too, like it already ignores `.well-known`:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known|vite)
```

But since this is a local dev server, you probably won't need this rule in the first place, because there is no security issue within your local machine anyway (and if you'd want to test an environment similar to production, then you wouldn't use a dev server either, and then the rule wouldn't be an issue).